# Python pandas - count elements which have a number in every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with some elements missing - the values are NaN. I would like to count the non-NaN values values in every row.

The following does not work:

```
total = (countries_return != "nan" ).sum(axis = 1)
```

Comment: Simply try `df.count()`. By default, it gives the non-Nan count

Comment: you can use ```df.notnull().count(axis=1)``` instead of writing a couple of lines